# How to exit from query result viewer in psql?

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell, debian, psql

First query:

```
database=# select * from table limit 1;
...
 |
(1 row)

(END)
```

I want to make a second query but I can't. ctrl+Z exits from psql. What can I press to exit only from result viewing?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Hit <kbd>q</kbd>. This closes many vim-like views, not only in psql, but also e.g. in 'less', 'git log', 'mutt', and many more.

Just FYI: Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> does not exit psql, it just suspends it and sends it to background. The program continues to run, and you can resume it by entering 'fg'. In Unix environments, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is usually the way to forcibly stop a program.

Comment: and be sure that you are on English keyboard) hitting q doesn't work when other language is active